# Space thriller movie where two humans try to cross the edge of normal space in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

The movie is not told linearly, if I remember correctly; sometimes one day passes, sometimes a few years. There are only two people on the ship, who try to get to the edge of normal space and discover what's behind it.

On the ship are also worms, which are meant to tell the time (not sure, though). They go missing near the end of the movie.

Something is broken in the ship and one of the crew members is trying to fix it and the other one dies by accident.

Sometimes the movie shows why they are on their way to the edge of space and some interviews with the crew before the start.

The ship interior was mostly white.

I watched the movie around eight years ago, but would guess it was much older than that, judging by the style; likely from the '70s-'90s. I don't think it's later than that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this film?

Comment: Around 8 years ago. But I think the movie is much older. At least 90s from the style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Beyond the Edge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2278870/)***, AKA *ISRA 88*, AKA *Mission 88* (2016).

From IMDB:

> A scientist and a pilot volunteer for a high profile mission to reach the end of the universe. After 13 years, the ship crashes through the end of the universe and into the unknown.

From a [review](https://www.irishfilmcritic.com/movie-review-beyond-edge-fails-capitalize-intriguing-ideas/):

> **The film stars Sean Maher (“Firefly”) as Dr. Abe Anderson and Casper Van Dien (“Starship Troopers”) as Lieutenant Colonel Harold Richards. When we first meet them, they have already spent 13 years on a mission to reach the end of the universe.** Harold serves as the pilot of the spacecraft, and Abe is there to do experiments on bees and eels. There isn’t much to do; Harold does pushups while Abe watches old sitcoms. There is also a pinball machine that may or may not work.
>
> It’s difficult to explain the plot beyond that. **The film keeps the audience in the dark by telling its story non-chronologically,** and although the structure plays into some of the concepts that are eventually explored, it makes for a bizarrely-paced film that I found very hard to engage with. For the first twenty minutes or so, the two men hardly speak to each other. It isn’t until later in the film that we really get to see them interact or learn anything about who they are. I don’t think the writers had a good sense of how to tease the ideas they were getting at, and in the end they never explain the ideas directly enough for any of the third-act reveals to feel significant or really make sense.

Two men volunteer for a spaceflight to the edge of the universe to find out what lies beyond it. The plot unfolds in non-chronological order, so we start off with them already in space, and are later shown scenes with them being prepped for the mission back on Earth.

They keep bees and one or more electric eels on board the ship, which I'm guessing are the 'worms' you mentioned. There's also a scene with one of the men trying to repair a broken pinball machine, and one of them dies in an accident.

The ship interior is mostly light grey, not white, but there are white objects within it, such as a table with a glowing white surface. The film is pretty low-budget, and the visuals have a Kubrickian feel at times, so it could be mistaken for being somewhat older than it actually is.

I could say more, but I've already matched all the details mentioned in the question, and don't want to spoil the plot for anyone who might want to watch this. I do agree with the review above though that much of what we see in the film isn't clearly explained.