# Star Wars ripoff from the 2010s in which a Han Solo knockoff is sent to save a princess and fight an evil overlord

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I did not watch the movie but saw its preview on MX Player (this may not be available outside my country).

I remember laughing after seeing the plot - It was nearly same as that of *Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope*  - "A bounty hunter was sent to save a princess and (maybe a prince too) and fight an evil overlord".

The poster had a Han Solo knockoff and the preview effects were very low budget.  Furthermore, the main lead was most certainly the Han Solo knockoff, and I say Han Solo as he was wearing a leather jacket akin to that of Solo. The preview also had a very short mid space fight scene. Again, I only saw the preview, but I could spot everything that's common in *Star Wars* - blasters, dark hooded evil overlord, a princess (smaller than Leia, perhaps 10-12 years old), a prince, and space battles with fighters. If I had to blindly guess, I would put the movie around 2010s but I am not very sure.

As for the actors, the main lead (Han Solo knockoff) had a trimmed short beard, wore clothing very similar to Han Solo in *A New Hope* and carried a blaster. The actress playing the princess was young, but maybe 1-2 years older than the actress who played Leia in the *Kenobi* show. The prince was also young, around 10-12 years old. The villain was most certainly a lot like Darth Vader.

The title 100 percent had either "Star" or "Wars" in it. Blind guess - had "Galactic" in it but not sure.

As for the language, I am not sure as even the preview was dubbed in Hindi, but the movie was foreign for certain.

What's the name of this movie?

The movie is not listed [here](https://screenrant.com/ten-star-wars-rip-off-movies-that-are-unintentionally-hilarious/) or [here](https://www.ign.com/articles/star-wars-rip-offs).

Comment: Um... what other details do you have? :-D It feels like that describes a number of possible films. Was it in English?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, have added a lot of details, dont remember anything more than that.

Comment: Having a child princess may help a lot, as many of the knockoffs went the "sex sells" route.

Comment: Starcrash is the usual answer to the question *'what is this star wars knock-off?'*

Comment: Hmm. The very youg princess rules out *The Ice Pirates*, *Starcrash* and *Battle Beyond the Stars*. which all were cheap, early *Star Wars* rip-offs.

Comment: If it is new, it probably cannot be *Dünyayı Kurtaran Adam*, a Turkish movie that actually used *Star Wars* footage.

Comment: It's probably The Force Awakens, the most blatant ripoff of A New Hope ever released.

Comment: Was it intended as a parody, or a serious movie? (In the former case, I see no-one's mentioned [Spaceballs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/) yet…)

Comment: @gidds - _Spaceballs_ was the first answer submitted, but it was deleted by the author after the OP confirmed that it's not the film they were looking for. That deleted answer is still visible to any user with the [access to moderator tools](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege.

Comment: By the way, guys, do you know that Star Wars itself is also a ripoff from older material? Check the "Lord Tedric" series from E.E. Doc Smith. There's a "Black Knight in a huge Iron Sphere", and he is half man, half machine. There's laser words, the force, etc.

Comment: I doubt that George Lucas copied the Force from Smith, if only because he copied it from Taoism first.

Comment: Han Solo wasn't a bounty hunter or soldier of fortune.  Anyway, "lone gunman saves damsel in distress from evil villain" was a trope of Westerns in the 1920s-1950s.

Comment: Not the answer, but see [Hardware Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_Wars)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is ***[Star Raiders: The Adventures of Saber Raine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Raiders:_The_Adventures_of_Saber_Raine)*** (2017).

[image: Poster for "Star Raiders: The Adventures of Saber Raine."]

> **A prince and princess are abducted from their planet. Saber Raine, a soldier of fortune is hired to bring them back. Along with three others, he embarks on the mission. They end up on a planet in the depths of space which is run by an evil overlord called Sinjin.** Having been freed from centuries of containment in a cryogenic prison, Sinjin is now teaming up with beings called the Quintari who have caused havoc throughout the galaxy. Sinjin has a plan of revenge against his betrayers' descendants and he has a powerful weapon.

- It is a low budget space opera movie from the 2010s, with "Star" in the title.
- Casper Van Dien plays the lead, who matches your description.
- There is a dark hooded "evil overlord," visible at around the 0:54 mark in the trailer below.
- The plot does centre around the abduction and subsequent rescue of a prince and princess, who are visible at around the 0:13 mark in the trailer below. (They look older than 10-12 years old, though.)
- Some shots of a spaceship battle can be seen in the trailer below, at around the 0:37 mark.

Comment: I admit I have horribly misjudged what a 10 year old looks like

Comment: Poor Casper Van Dien, what happened to you? I really liked Starship Troopers as well.

Comment: How do films like this get produced? What is the motivation for those participating?

Comment: @ThaRobster - He must've fallen on hard times. This [isn't the only low budget sci-fi film he appeared in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/261543/122024) around that time.

Comment: @LamarLatrell If you got a chance to make a movie, or even have a significant part in a movie, which was a step above "kids in the backyard with a cheap camera", would you turn it down because it wasn't going to be a blockbuster?  Wouldn't it be a blast to show it to your family and friends, even if it wasn't Oscar-worthy?  Plus it's a paying gig.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MoneyDearBoy plays into a lot of cases, although that trope also lists a number of other reasons ranging from that they really like the idea of the film, they're doing it as a favor, they want to go "on location" for vacation, they're funding other work, or because they want their kids to see them in something.

Comment: Obligatory mention that this was given the Rifftrax treatment:
https://www.rifftrax.com/rifftrax-live-star-raiders

Comment: Why does this look like an episode of Stargate SG-1? Locations? Lighting/camera techniques?

Comment: @AndreKR bad acting, bad writing, cheap special effects.

Comment: @Kyralessa should note, I have worked in film. Personally, I'd much much rather hone my skills on a short film and making that *perfect* than a feature where efforts are diluted over time.

Comment: To answer your questions directly, 'got a chance' ..I'd *make* the chance. Blockbuster prospects or not, I'd be taking a good look at the showreels of those already involved. Working on film can be a blast (or really not) independent of budget, bring your own smile .

Answer (score 4):

If I hadn't seen that you were asking about a movie in the 2010's, my first thought would've been Mel Brooks' awesome 1987 Star Wars parody *[Spaceballs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/)*.

[image: Spaceballs Movie Poster]

- Bill Pullman plays the "Han Solo knockoff"
- Rick Moranis is the "dark hooded evil overlord"
- John Candy is the Chewbacca knockoff
- Mel Brooks is your Yoda

Even if this isn't what you were referring to, it's basically *the* Star Wars parody film (at least in my opinion), and I can't recommend you check it out more.